# How are decision trees potentially unstable?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I was reading "Decision Trees for Analytics Using SAS Enterprise Miner" and one passage states that decision trees are potentially unstable, but it doesn't explain why. How are they unstable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture on the website of scikit-learn about decision trees might also help with your intuition about it:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

It just shows that over-fitting in decision trees can lead to drastic results.

Answer (score 1):

Decision trees can potentially be unstable if there is a small variation in the data that may result in a completely different tree being generated.  You can combat this by using a variety of ensemble methods such as bagging,  boosting or stacking.